# How to use Alt+` to switch between windows of the same application

Tags: gnome, 20.04, shortcut-keys, xorg

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04. On Ubuntu 18.04 I got used to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> through my open applications and then selecting the appropriate window using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Since I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04, the window switching behavior has changed. Now I can only use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through all of the windows (instead of applications) that are open. Initially there was no key binding set for cycling between windows of t  he same application. I used the settings GUI to set cycling through windows of an application to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

The problem that I am facing currently is that I cannot use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I can see all the windows open instead of all the applications.

[image: When I use Alt+Tab I see open windows]

When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, I can see the icons for all the applications, but I can only use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle through the windows open for the application that is in focus currently/most recently used application.

[image: When I use Alt+` I see open applications]

I can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> in tandem to seamlessly switch between windows anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings → *Keyboard shortcuts* and change the *Switch applications* shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and the *Switch windows of an application* shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then hit <kbd>`</kbd> grave key while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to achieve what you are expecting.